# Tips for closing a gap between outside door and floor

Tags: insulation, doors, door-frame

The door to my new apartment has a large gap that allows cold air to flow in

What is the best, simplest and most effective way to plug this gap?

[image: door gap to floor]

Comment: What's on the the other side? The outside or a hallway?

Comment: On the other side of the door is the raw elements

Answer (score 0):

Use a brush seal

[image]

This will significantly reduce the air leakage, but also prevents the floor from being damaged if there are objects in the way.

If the floor is not prone to damage, you can use more solid material.

Comment: Perhaps OP should also confirm that the opening is not required for HVAC. Some apartment buildings heat/cool with pressurized hallways.

Comment: @P2000 good point. It's not

Answer (score 0):

On my front door I used this product:

[image: self-stick weatherstrip]

It can be straightened out to a flat strip, and has stayed put for many years.

On my side door I used this:

[image: garage door weatherstrip]

with the top and bottom edges cut off. My doors are dark colored, I hope you can find something in white.